# Web API - Get information encrypted inside token, ticket ExpiresUtc and IssuedUtc

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, asp.net-web-api2, access-token

I am using Web API as my back-end and implemented the token security using the built in mechanism. In the template code, when issuing the access token, I can get the issued and expired dates of the token:

```
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
{
    var issued = context.Properties.IssuedUtc;
    var expired = context.Properties.ExpiresUtc;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Now when a request is made to a method that requires authorization I want to do something similar:

```
[Authorize]
public async Task<string> GetTokenInfo()
{
    //var issued = GetCurrentTicket().Properties.ExpiresUtc;
    //var issued = GetCurrentTicket().Properties.IssuedUtc;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

So how can I get the information encrypted inside the token, more specifically the **ExpireUtc** and **IssuedUtc** ?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily retrieve the `AuthenticationProperties` dictionary using `IAuthenticationManager.AuthenticateAsync`, which returns a `AuthenticateResult` object: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn270674(v=vs.113).aspx

From a Web API controller, you'll need the `GetOwinContext` extension to get the OWIN context from the request message and use `IOwinContext.Authentication`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.owinhttprequestmessageextensions.getowincontext(v=vs.118).aspx

```
var context = Request.GetOwinContext();
var result = await context.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
if (result == null) {
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}

var properties = result.Properties;
```

(of course, you also need to have a properly configured `app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication` call in your `Startup` class, but I assume it's the case here).

Comment: @Yaron Levi: did that help?

Comment: Properties are into Result property of result:
var properties = result.Result.Properties and I have installed 
 Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin to see the GetOwinContext() method.

Comment: @Evilripper actually no, the syntax is correct. Make sure you're correctly awaiting the `Task` returned by `AuthenticateAsync`.

Comment: Ah okay, I forgot that my method is not async. This answer is the simplest way to get this information and it must be accepted like best answer.